# On Android 7.1 (API 25) LocationManager crashes with Fatal Exception in android.location.LocationListener.onStatusChanged

Tags: android, android-location

When I run my app location enabled app in an Android 6.0 device or Android 10 everything works fine, but when I run it in an Android 7.1 device it crashes right after the user gives location permission with the following message:

```
Process: com.hkc.incidencias, PID: 6853
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "void android.location.LocationListener.onStatusChanged(java.lang.String, int, android.os.Bundle)"
    at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:304)
    at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.-wrap0(LocationManager.java)
    at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:242)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

My Fragment implements `LocationListener` and it takes care of checking the user permissions previous to requesting location updates.

```
private void startLocationUpdates() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // Start updating the user location with a minimum update time and distance set so it doesn't affect too much the battery life.
    // Every time the position of the user changes, the onLocationChanged function will be called
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 20000, 10, this);
}
```

And then it overrides onLocationChanged:

```
// The position of the user has changed
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(@NonNull Location location) {
    // Store the user position
    myPosition = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
   
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that in build.gradle (:app) if I have both `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` with a value of `30` the code compiles just fine.  But if I change those values to `29` the code won't compile saying that I need to implement the following methods of `LocationListener`

```
@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
```

With this changes, it works in all the tested devices even after going back to API 30